# Download index compositions with R

Tags: r, finance

I am looking for a package/way that would allow me to download index compositions from various websites.
Index compositions changes rarely and are easily available but I can't find any csv available online.

How can I load say the [CAC 40](https://indices.nyx.com/fr/products/indices/FR0003500008-XPAR) definition ?

PS: What I care about are the names/isin/sicovam not really the weights in the index

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a request for a data source; not about programming.

Comment: nonsense see bellow...

Comment: Even if I did concede that it _is_ a programming question, it should still be closed because: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)"

Comment: ok this one I agree :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the composition of the [CAC40](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAC_40) at Wikipedia, and download and process with package [`XML`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XML/index.html).

The function `readHTMLTable()` is particularly useful, since it will find and parse all tables on the page.  In this case the relevant table is the second, hence the index `[[2]]` in the code. Try:

```
library(XML)
url <- "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAC_40"
dat <- readHTMLTable(url)[[2]]

 head(dat[, 1:3])
        Company           ICB Sector Ticker symbol
1         Accor               hotels            AC
2   Air Liquide  commodity chemicals            AI
3        Alstom industrial machinery           ALO
4 ArcelorMittal                steel            MT
5           AXA  full line insurance            CS
6   BNP Paribas                banks           BNP
```

---

The same code also works for the FTSE 100:

```
url <- "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTSE_100_Index"
dat <- readHTMLTable(url)[[2]]
head(dat[, 1:3])
                   Company          Sector Market cap (Ã‚Â£bn)
1        Royal Dutch Shell     Oil and gas                 135
2                     HSBC         Banking                 129
3                       BP     Oil and gas                  85
4           Vodafone Group       Telecomms                  83
5          GlaxoSmithKline Pharmaceuticals                  73
6 British American Tobacco         Tobacco                  69
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted ! Thanks